# How are the ranking points decided for a win/draw/loss over PES 2012 online quick matches?

Tags: psn, pro-evolution-soccer-2012

Sometimes I win and get 8 points, sometimes I get 10, etc.
The worst thing is, sometimes I draw and lose points while the opponent gains some.

It was brought to my attention that the teams you've chosen might be a factor in deciding how many points are gained or lost, but is there an exact formula or a way to determine the amount beforehand?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on you and your opponent's ranking as well.

Say if your rating is 500 and your opponent is 600, a draw will cost your opponent some points while you gain points.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but what is the formula? The reason I'm asking is sometimes you might want to go bunker and get a draw for 4-5 points, while some other times you might want to just attack as much as possible to win, even if you are in a tie right now, as you will lose a lot of points...

Comment: Not always the case. I thought it was the rankings of both players involved that determined the points gained/lost. However, I won against someone 50 points over me and gained 9. I then lost a game to a player 18 short of me and lost 14. I'm not sure how that can be decided by any particular formula. I have also drawn with an opponent with more points than me and in a higher division and actually lost 1 point! There must be some other deciding factor that we are not made aware of.